# Symfony2 cannot persist column that has a relationship

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, auto-increment

I have a Boards entity and a Shares entity. A board can have many shares( as in a user shared a board he made with another user).

The Boards entity has an auto inc. column called boardId. The shares entity has a column with the same name that maps a share to a board. Here is the code to map it:

Boards:

```
/**
 *  @orm:OneToMany(targetEntity="Shares", mappedBy="boards", cascade={"persist",  "remove"})
 */
private $shares;
```

Shares:

```
/**
 * @orm:ManyToOne(targetEntity="Boards", inversedBy="shares")
 * @orm:JoinColumns({
 *   @orm:JoinColumn(name="board_id", referencedColumnName="board_id")
 * })
 */
private $boards;
```

When I persist a new Share as so:

```
 $share = new Shares();
 $share->setMemberIdT($members[0]->getMemberId());
 $share->setMemberIdF($id);
 $share->setBoardId($boards[0]->getBoardId());
 $share->setDateShared();
 $share->setReceived(0);
```

I'm calling the boardId as so:

```
 $boards = $em->getRepository('PixbellyHomeBundle:Boards')
    ->findByBoardId($board);
```

I have echoed out the the boardId up until, literally, the line before and the id is correct, however when I call persist, I get this error:

```
"response":{"errorInfo":["23000",1048,"Column 'board_id' cannot be null"]}}
```

I think it has to do with the relationship but I have tried it all and nothing, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing something like:

```
$share->setBoards($boards);
```

Comment: I got `call to undefined method`, this one is really confusing me.

Comment: you have a property called boards. You should have a setter method for that property, which would be setBoards(). If you don't have it you should add it. Or you can use the doctrine: generate: entities command to have doctrine generate it for you.

Comment: Carlos, you led me in the right direction. I had to use this `$board = $em->getReference('PixbellyHomeBundle:Boards', $board_id);
      
      $share->setBoardId($board->getBoardId());`  Lol, the problem is now it breaks my join statement, I can't win!